# Modify Elasticsearch score

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of products in my e-commerce store.
For each product, I am storing the list of users who bought it and the sales counter next to each, in addition, I store metadata such as the product name and price.

I am looking to use Elasticsearch to search for products by their name(Relevance search), and when a user will search for a specific product it will narrow down to his context and do a search for product by name and give a higher score for products that he used to buy in the past.

What is the best way to solve it in Elasticsearch?
(1) How should I model it?  I came up with a solution to store everything in one index (product index)
But I am not if it's a good solution as it doesn't make much sense to store all the historical sales for each user as part of each product.
(2) How to change the score function based on user sales history.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and easy to use is to boost the field which stores  `the number of times it was purchased` and include this in your query somehow.

Refer [boosting elasticsearch query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-boosting-query.html) for above.

If you are looking for elegant solution as above field is a metadata and it doesn't make sense to boost it index time or query time(which is difficult to change as well), then would suggest using the [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) query which can be easily changed as well and is much elegant way and easy to customize as well(you can include various other metadata as well like age of product, views etc to further improve relevance).

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean in option 1. Option 2 seems to be more relevant... Also I edited my question just to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: @MasterOfPuppets option 1 is simplest like some fields tags in SO post is more important in search query and if they are found in document than, boost that document by some factor.

Comment: Sorry but this no answer my question